# Prove that if $a \in R$ is invertible, central, idempotent, or nilpotent, respectively, then so is $\phi (a)$ in S.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let R and S be rings and $\phi : R \to S$ a surjective ring homomorphism.
Prove that if $a \in R$ is invertible, central, idempotent, or nilpotent, respectively, then so is $\phi (a)$ in S. How about converses?

For $a \in R$ is invertible. We can write $\phi (a.a^{-1})=\phi (a) \phi (a^{-1})=e$

But where do we use surjection? And how can we comment about converse?

Comment: surjection is used for the others. Work on the rest first

Comment: I looked others and dont need to use surjection. I guess when we do for converse we should use surjection since we can find an element(talk about there is an corresponding element). Am i right?

Comment: How did you show that $\varphi(a)$ is central?

Comment: If a is central then ar=ra (r is an element of R). Then $\phi(ar) = \phi(ra) = \phi(a) \phi(r) = \phi(r) \phi(a)$

Comment: Oh i understand we should use surjection to say every element of S. But how do we comment about converses i still dont know?

Comment: For converses, think about maps from $\mathbb{Z}$ to its quotients for all but central; and use matrices to check central.